# How to make atomic operation with both file system and database in Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, file, filesystems, atomic

I think the following should be a pretty common pattern :

- A database is used to store file paths
- The files themselves are stored in the file system

Issues may occur when say we want to modify a file path : we need to both modify 
the database file path and to move the file in the filesystem. It is important that this is done "atomically". Indeed, while we are doing the modification, another process may attempt to read the file path in the datadase and then tries to access the file in the file system. We should make sure that the tuple

("file path", "actual file location")

remains consistant all the time.

Is there a canonical/simple way to achieve this with Postgres/Linux ?

Comment: Hard to say without a bit more context. The "simple" way would be to lock the database record against updates while you're accessing the file. How practical this is for you (and how disastrous it would be for concurrency) depends a lot on your application.

Answer (score 1):

One of the major features of the database is that the processes see it consistently. That also means that different clients see different state of the database.

This means that when you correct a file path in the database and commit the change any transactions that started before the commit can see the old path for some time after the commit.

So actually to make sure nobody would try to read the old file path you have to wait until all transactions from before the commit would end. That can take milliseconds or, in extreme situations, days. If you have a

I'd try to implement the following scheme (pseudocode):

```
sql("begin")
os.hardlink(old_path, new_path)
sql("update files set path=? where path=?, new_path, old_path)
sql("insert into files_to_clean values (?, txid_current())", old_path)
sql("commit")

if random()<CLEANUP_PROBABILITY:
  sql("begin")
  for delete_path in sql("
    delete from files_to_clean
    where txid<txid_snapshot_xmin(txid_current_snapshot())
    returning path skip locked
  "):
    os.delete(delete_path)
  sql("commit")
```

Comment: What if someone select a path before it is modified, and then tries to read the corresponding file, after the file is being deleted (by os.delete(delete_path)) ? maybe you do something to make it work with "skip locked" ?